# CE 5.0 with 3G Usb Stick

Tags: usb, windows-ce, 3g

I'm new to CE programming and I have a Marvel device PXA270 with Windows CE 5.0 installed. The device has one usb port.

I wonder if there's ANYTHING I can try to connect a 3G-HDSPA usb stick to it. When plugged it only recognises its folders as a pendrive would do, but no Internet.

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget it. To make it work you need OS support for it or a dedicated infrastructure that the cellular modem should provide for Windows CE 5.

To have cellular support you need Cellcore included in the OS and Windows CE 5 does not support it.

What you can do is start develop your own infrastructure for the device, but it will take you several months of work and that is if you have the Cellcore code from Windows CE 6 as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you must have a Windows CE driver for the device.  Obviously it's a composite device that enumerates as a storage device and also whatever the radio is.  Windows CE understands the storage device part and therefore loads up the driver for that.  It has no idea what the radio is.

You would have to either get a driver from the OEM (they probably don't have one, though it's always worth checking) or write your own (you probably don't have enough info on the radio chipset to be able to do that).